# Bucketing a tupled Tensorflow dataset where each tupled element has different shapes

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, batch-processing, tensorflow-datasets, bucket

I am trying to modify an existing tensorflow code. First, a 2d matrix of words is converted to a `dataset` from a `geneartor` and by `map_strings_to_ints` function and converted into vocab index. Then the following function is called.

```
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.bucket_by_sequence_length(element_length_func=lambda d: tf.shape(d)[0],
                                                                     bucket_boundaries=bucket_boundaries,
                                                                     bucket_batch_sizes=bucket_batch_sizes,
                                                                     padded_shapes=dataset.output_shapes,
                                                                     padding_values=constants.PAD_VALUE))
```

where each of the `dataset` elements was an array of size [None, None] (i.e., 2d mat).

Now for each element, I like to add another sequence of text. So each element is a tuple of previous 2d mat and the corresponding sentence/sequence that is each of the new dataset elements is a tuple of ([None, None],[None]), then how can I modify the above function?

I tried

```
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.bucket_by_sequence_length(element_length_func=lambda d,t: tf.shape(d)[0],
                                                                     bucket_boundaries=bucket_boundaries,
                                                                     bucket_batch_sizes=bucket_batch_sizes,
                                                                     padded_shapes=dataset.output_shapes,
                                                                     padding_values=constants.PAD_VALUE))
```

and few other tricks but got

```
TypeError: If shallow structure is a sequence, input must also be a sequence. Input has type: <class ‘int’>
```

Note that, the `dataset` elements are words mapped into vocab index (i.e., int)

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful for you:

```
X = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9], [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]])
Y = np.array([0,1,0])

def elements_gen():
    for x,y in zip(X,Y):
        yield (x,y)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=elements_gen, output_shapes=([None, None], []), output_types=(tf.int32, tf.int32))

dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.bucket_by_sequence_length(element_length_fun =lambda x,y: tf.shape(x)[0], bucket_boundaries=[4,7], bucket_batch_sizes=[2,2,2], padding_values=(0,0)))
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
```

The issue is just what the error says, because the structure you are padding is a sequence the value used to pad the structure must be a sequence as well.

Comment: I tried that. But in my case Y is a 2d array [[i,go], [total,value,is], [not,so,bad]] and I got that error